# Bootstrap ~ "aria-expanded" not accept by element <a>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, netbeans-8

I lack of idea why the sample copy from `Bootstrap` are not able to workout and keep throwing the error message on below:

> Attribute "aria-expanded" not allowed on element "a" at this point.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Log-In</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" >
                                Management <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="presentation">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li> 
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

Anyone have face the same problem before? Please help!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below

```
<li class="dropdown active">
```

or

```
<li class="dropdown active open">
```

instead of directly setting

```
aria-expanded="false"
```

and

```
aria-expanded="true"
```

respectively

Comment: thanks for advice, but finally i realize the issue was caused by the import library... of course i also remove the aria-expanded attribute in the element then the error are removed. Anyway, thanks :)